# Modulo C# is not producing expected value

Tags: c#, visual-studio, double, division, modulo

I try to check whether 2 doubles are divisible, so I can conclude whether a given point is on a certain grid or not. I use the % operator, but I seem to do something wrong because the output is not what I expect.

In this example I try to divide 5 by 0.2, the result should be 25.0, but the modulo operator doesn't show this to me. As can be seen in the image;

```
double LUpDown.Value = 20
double nUpDown.Value = 100
double stepx = LUpDown.Value / double nUpDown.Value = 0.2
double xvalp = 5
```

then when I compute the % operator things go wrong;

```
xvalp % stepx = 0.1999999999..... ??
```

I expect a 0 because 5/0.2 = 25.0

[image]

Comment: This would be worth a look: https://floating-point-gui.de/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try using `decimal` instead of `double` ?

Comment: wow thanks! Still wondering why doubles don't work, but my problem is solved! thanks allot

Comment: @BillyBouw Even decimal won't help for all cases. Consider: `decimal a = 1m; decimal b = 3m; decimal c = a / b; decimal d = b % c;` You would probably expect `d` to be 0, but in fact it works out to `0.0000000000000000000000000003`

Comment: Is this a question or an answer?